# Trying to the log files with tailf -f pretty print json part and leave headers not converted

Tags: linux, bash, grep, alias, tail

One line example of log file:

```
2018-07-30T10:47:23.027Z|SomeInfo|DEBUG|4141dadfawe||Sending request:{"some":{"json":"eggsspam"}}
```

My alias:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@10.143.3.51 
    -p614 "tail 
    -f  /var/opt/pathtolog/log.log" | grep 
    -o --line-buffered \{.*\:\{.*\:.*\}\} | jq .
}
```

So right now I'm reading a log file using tail -f via ssh, grep only json and send it to jq. This part is working fine and json is well formated but I'm losing headers.

To sum up:
**2018-07-30T10:47:23.027Z|SomeInfo|DEBUG|4141dadfawe||Sending request:** I want to print this part unchanged and then pretty print well formated json `{
  "some": {
    "json": "eggsspam"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Probably this could help, it is using `awk`, for example:

```
echo '2018-07-30T10:47:23.027Z|SomeInfo|DEBUG|4141dadfawe||Sending request:{"some":{"json":"eggsspam"}}' \
| awk -F"request:" '{ print $1"requests:"; print $2 | "jq" }'
```

It will output:

```
2018-07-30T10:47:23.027Z|SomeInfo|DEBUG|4141dadfawe||Sending requests:
{
  "some": {
    "json": "eggsspam"
  }
}
```

It works by using the delimiter `-F"request:"` and then passing only to `jq` the second column, in this case, the json that needs to be pretty printed `print $2 | "jq"`

This is an example searching for json using `{.*\}` as a pattern, something that definitely could be improved, in this case the json must the the last part of the log to work:

```
$ echo '2018-07-30T10:47:23.027Z|SomeInfo|DEBUG|4141dadfawe||Sending request:{"some":{"json":"eggsspam"}}' \
| awk 'match($0, /\{.*\}/) {
    print substr($0, 0, length($0)-RLENGTH);
    print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) | "jq"
}'
```

It will also output:

```
2018-07-30T10:47:23.027Z|SomeInfo|DEBUG|4141dadfawe||Sending request:
{
  "some": {
    "json": "eggsspam"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this could work if "request" would be only one delimiter unfortunatelly there are much more e.g.: notification:, dump:, message(no colon sign)..

Comment: @PrzemysławGrenda you can use a regex as a field delimiter

Comment: But then json part will be excluded from output.

Comment: @PrzemysławGrenda check updated answer, it should work if your json is the last part of the file.